# Visual Studio 2015 - Original RGB Format is not valid value for Int32

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with my Visual Studio 2015 .

I need to change my background color in **Properties** tab. When I'm putting original RGB code like `(20,20,20)`, it will give me an error:

> "20,20,20 is not a valid value for Int32"

I know. I can change it in the program Source Code

When changed format to `20;20;20,` it works fine.

Can somebody help me?

I will be really happy if there is a way to change default value format to classic RGB.

Comment: what technology are you using, winforms, wpf, uwp apps?

Comment: I'm using winforsm

Comment: It works for me.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is may because of your region setting
check this in control panel
[image: change List separator]